# Centering a window with command line

Tags: window-manager

Is there a command to center the active window in the middle of the screen?  Compiz has a feature called "center", but it effectively shows the window fully maximized.  I'm looking for the size to be smaller and I'm unclear on how to change it to a smaller size.

Comment: Before do anything, write down your idea more clear. If you can, draw a before-after wireframe for better understanding.